# Removing border from WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I've got a WebBrowser control sitting on a Form which has an irritating 2px inset-looking border around it. It's causing my content to be clipped by 4 px on the right and bottom, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. The control itself doesn't have any BorderStyle properties -- how does one remove the border?

See the red area in the screen shot:

[Make it stop! http://img229.imageshack.us/img229/8342/badbadwebbrowser.gif](http://img229.imageshack.us/img229/8342/badbadwebbrowser.gif)

I want the WebBrowser to look like the blue area -- that is, to fill the Form and be flush against the Form's edges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE draws that as part of the default style on the body tag.  Set `border:0px` on the body element and it goes away.

Thankfully, this is [going away in IE9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/making-sites-look-their-best-in-standards-mode).

Comment: Good call. I had been resetting the margins and padding, but didn't remove any borders that may be on the html or body elements. Thanks!

Comment: Can you not add CSS to the page, or is a CSS-based approach not working? You may be able to programmatically add CSS to accomplish this from your application.

Comment: This does not work on MSIE 9 if you have a <!DOCTYPE html> and use an embedded browser.

Comment: Well this answer is 7 years old.

Answer (score 3):

WebBrowser control inherits display style from control class. If you want to control the border style of control, you can use code like that, e.g. in Form.Designer.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public class wbExt : System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
    {
        private BorderStyle _borderStyle;
        [
        Category("Appearance"),
        Description("The border style")
        ]

        public BorderStyle BorderStyle
        {
            get
            {
                return _borderStyle;
            }
            set
            {
                _borderStyle = value;
                this.RecreateHandle();
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                const int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;
                const int WS_EX_STATICEDGE = 0x00020000;
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                switch (_borderStyle)
                {
                    case BorderStyle.FixedSingle:
                        cp.Style |= WS_BORDER;
                        break;
                    case BorderStyle.Fixed3D:
                        cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_STATICEDGE;
                        break;
                }
                return cp;
            }
        }

        public wbExt()
        {
        }
    }
```

Now you can change generated code in Form class.

```
private wbExt webBrowser1;
```

and rewrite creation of webBrowser item in InitializeComponent of form, like that:

```
this.webBrowser1 = new WindowsFormsApplication1.wbExt();
```

So, now

```
webBrowser1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
```

will remove any borders from webBrowser control.

Comment: Thank you for the code sample. As it turns out, my real problem was with the document I was loading into the control, and not the control itself.

Comment: This answer is completyely wrong. The border we are talking about here is INSIDE the browser control NOT outside.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved the same problem by adding `border:none;` style attribute into the **html** element.

```
<html style="border:none;">
```

First I tried to add it into the **body** element but It didn't work, but it works on root **html** element.

The IE version used on Windows XP for WebBrowser object - I think the version 6 - interprets the root html element as having a border by default. If you have direct control over the web page displayed in the WebBrowser, you can add a style attribute directly to the HTML source of the page - as I did -, If not, There should be a way to edit the HTML inside the WebBrowser programmatically on the side of your application.

Comment: This does not work on IE 9. The only way to remove that stupid border is by removing the <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score -1):

I cannot reproduce the appearance you are telling about. My code in the Form1.Designer.cs is:

```
    this.webBrowser1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.webBrowser1.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
    this.webBrowser1.Name = "webBrowser1";
    this.webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    this.webBrowser1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(141, 125);
    this.webBrowser1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.webBrowser1.Uri = ....
```

and the webcontrol is shown without the border... I'm using VS 2008 SP1/Windows 7.

Maybe you should try to add the control inside a container, e.g. a panel.

Comment: View your form on xp and you'll see exactly like in the question. Win7 doesn't show borders.

Comment: @Hasan: It has nothing to do with the Windows version. It depends on the browser version!