# WPF controls not displaying over transparent opaque window

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, opacity, transparent

I am trying to make a transparent window and on this window I am trying to display small web browser controls that would be nontransparent. I can't get it to work, the web browser control is loading and you can even click the links in the control, but it is not visible... any help is appreciated

```
<Window ...        
Title="HelpView" Height="300" Width="300" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" >
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.6" Color="Black"/>
</Window.Background>
<Canvas Name="HelpCanvas">
    <StackPanel>
        <WebBrowser Width="150" Height="150" Source="http://www.msn.com"></WebBrowser>
    </StackPanel>
</Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: Looks like a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444457/c-sharp-wpf-displaying-webbrowser-on-window-with-allowtransparency-true-does-n)

Comment: Indeed, it works if you remove AllowsTransparency="True".

Comment: If I remove AllowTransparency = "True", then the Window is no longer transparent. I want the window to be transparent, but display a small webbrowser control on this large window

Comment: I am making each webbrowser part of a new window, so on top of the main transparent window there will be several small windows that each contain a web browser control.. seems like a kludge but it works